# Discord embed title and description not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a custom help command using embeds. While making it, I found that when I add in a embed title and description during initialization, it prevents the embed from sending at all.
My code before title and description:

```
@commands.command(name="help")
async def help(self, ctx):

    test_e = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.orange())
    test_e.set_author(name="Snoof Bot Commands")
    test_e.add_field(name="test", value="Bot prefix = oof", inline=False)
    test_e.add_field(name="test", value="hello", inline=False)
    test_e.add_field(name="good day", value="today is a good day")

    await ctx.send(embed=test_e)
```

My code after adding title and description:

```
@commands.command(name="help")
async def help(self, ctx):

    test_e = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.orange(), title="title", description="desc")
    test_e.set_author(name="Snoof Bot Commands")
    test_e.add_field(name="test", value="Bot prefix = oof", inline=False)
    test_e.add_field(name="test", value="hello", inline=False)
    test_e.add_field(name="good day", value="today is a good day")

    await ctx.send(embed=test_e)
```

Comment: try putting the title and description before the color value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your title variable to the start and your colour variable to the end :)

`test_e = discord.Embed(title="title", description="desc",colour=discord.Colour.orange())`

[image]